# ETL for a frequently changing Table structure

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, etl, emr, amazon-emr

**Scenario**:

I have a Source which maintains the transactions data. They have around 900 columns and based on the requirements of the new business, they add additional columns.

We are a BI team and we only extract around 200 columns which are required for our reporting. But when new business is launched / new analysis is required, sometimes users approach us and request us to pull extra columns from the source.

**Current Design:**

We have created a table with extra columns for future columns as well.
We are maintaining a 400 column table with the future column names like str_01, str_02...., numer_01, numer_02... date_01, date_02... etc.

We have a mapping table which maps the columns in our table and columns in Source table. Using this mapping table, we extract the data from source.

**Problem:**

Recently, we have reached the 400 column limit of our table and we won't be able to onboard any new columns. One approach that we can implement is to modify the table to increase the columns to 500 (or 600) but I am looking for other solutions on how to implement ETL / design the table structure for these scenarios.

Comment: Redshift standard limits are 1600 columns and 400 sortkey columns. Is there are a reason each of your columns has to be a sortkey? Only sortkey the columns that represent the necessary composite key for the "row" you need. The other alternative is to switch to a different architecture (NoSQL) that is denormalized and schemaless. EMR supports Cassandra and HBase.

Comment: @cowbert ,By 400 column limit, i meant we have exhausted all the extra columns that we have created for our future use. They are not part of sort key. Our sort key is a date column on which users filter. I am open to NoSQL as well but we need a reporting solution on top of this. Not sure if NoSQL supports reporting solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your additional columns are measures, not dimensions. So you can keep the dimensions in the individual columns and include them into sort key, and store measures in JSON, accessing them whenever you need. Also if you can distinguish between frequently used measures vs. occasional you can store the frequently used ones in columns and the occasional ones in JSON. Redshift has native support for extracting the value given the key, and you also have the ability to set up Python UDFs for more complex processing.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the answer. This is really helpful. So If i understand correctly, i need to store all frequently used columns as individual columns and rest all other attributes as a JSON string. Couple of questions here: 1) The data type of JSON string is varchar in Redshift, correct? 2) Do you how this approach works for batch processing or reporting where we extract around 1 million records?

Comment: @KishoreKumar 1) yes, it's varchar. To get the value, you use `extract_json_path_text` function and convert the output to some numeric data type. 2) As long as your filtering, sorting and grouping are efficient (you are utilizing sort/dist keys and don't do joins that require shuffle between nodes) the aggregation of json key should be fine. I would appreciate if you test on your side and provide the feedback.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried the approach in Hive and below are couple of things i noticed:1) Hive doesn't have concatenate operator (||). we need to use CONCAT function to generate a JSON string from columns. This is getting too complicated especially when i am planning to create a JSON string from more than 100 columns. 2) While concatenating , we need to handle columns which can have NULLS as well. Else whole JSON string is becoming NULL. I am planning to create a UDF to generate JSON string in Hive. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: @KishoreKumar the approach that I have suggested is for Redshift... in Hive that might work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009608/combine-columns-from-multiple-columns-into-one-in-hive